# Is $P(T>c|T=k) = P(k>c|T=k)$?

Tags: probability

Is it acceptable to write:

$P(T>c|T=k) = P(k>c|T=k)$?

I think not, because k isn’t a random variable, but I have seen this written this way.

If C is a rv, does this change things?

$P(T>C|T=k) = P(k>C|T=k)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them can be written. The latter is the one you generally see; but the first one is like saying $P(1 < 2)$, which is actually 1, since 1 is always smaller than 2. We're in a limiting case here. Surely, you can define a [PMF](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Probability_mass_function) of the form:
$$
P_X(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & x =1 \\
      0 & x \neq 1
   \end{cases}
$$
It is not against the definition. But, this is a constant. In your case, $k$ or $c$ are also constants with similar PMFs. You don't violate RV definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Option 1 is ok. Random variables are allowed to be degenerate (implicit in this notation is that $k$ is a random variable that for all $\omega$ gives the value $k$). There may be some problems with this notation if the conditioning set has probability 0.

This is not so different from saying that the covariance of a random variable with a (constant) number is zero - even if strictly speaking we can only compute covariances between two random variables. The number is interpreted as a constant random variable,